# To change letter of word/C

Tags: c, arrays, alphabetical

I m  trying to write Encryption Algorithm.I change order of alphabet.

```
char alfabe[26]={'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
```

after changing i want to assign last to letter z and y but i couldnt to with these codes.

```
 strcpy(alfabe[25],"z");
         strcpy(alfabe[26],"y");
```

Comment: `alfeba` has a size of 26. It can only accept indecies from 0 to 25. You can't use `alfabet[26]`. 

Please give more details about what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

This will work for lower case letters at least:

```
char *p;
for(p = mystr; *p; p++)
    if(*p >= 'a' && *p <= 'z')
        *p = alfabe[*p-'a'];
```

But remember, [transposition is not encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transposition_cipher#Detection_and_cryptanalysis)!

Answer (score 0):

```
alfabe[24] = 'z';
alfabe[25] = 'y';
```

strcpy is absolutely the wrong thing to use here.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe clearest would be to write:

```
alfabe['y' - 'a'] = 'z';
alfabe['z' - 'a'] = 'y';
```

This makes it fairly obvious that you're swapping y and z in the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a simple transposition ([Caesar cypher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher)) mechanism more easily without manually defining an alphabet.

```
char* text;
int i, num_transpose;

for(i=0; a[i] != '\0'; i++)  
  if (a[i] >= 'a' && a[i] <= 'z')
    text[i] = (text[i] - 'a' + num_transpose) % ('z'-'a'+1) + 'a';
```

That would shift letters in your text by `num_transpose` places in alphabet. Note though that this will only work for lower-case ASCII letters.